# Multiple XML file with same root name refer to 1 XML schema: setting a unique key to element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, unique

Eg. I have two separate files with the same root name  which can be seen in employment.xml and education.xml. The common word between both files is the word "code". I would like to ensure that for "code" , the values do not get repeated in their respective files.

So moving onto schema, how do i make the verification for code only. Since apprently two selectors do not work in one . I am trying to prevent writing too any  and make the schema be reusable for more similar lists with "code".

My idea is to create a function like thing. In the sense, if it identifies "employmentstatus", then should result in 'xs:selector xpath = "employmentstatus"' and if identifies "education", then should result in '"xs:selector xpath = "education"' etc.

Is it possible in XML Schema? Any suggestions will be great?

***XML Files:***

**employment.xml**

[image]

**education.xml**

[image]

***XML Schema:***

**rootwithattribut.xsd**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"xs:selector xpath = "*" "

This works because * matches any element node. It works temporarily as I have only one element currently.
This has helped to get the element name. It works.